# How to query the value using populate in a Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to return one index's object of the array,
but when I query, It returns to me that all of the documents.

This is my Schema(userTb)

```
const userTbSchema = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  userId: String,
  gender: String
}
```

And this is my another Schema(product)

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  product: String,
  userTbId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "userTb", required: true },
}
```

And They are in another js file.
This is the result of the query of my Schema(product) using Populate.

```
{
    "_id": "5fc4c13f32ab3174acb01234",
    "product": "watch",
    "userTbId": {
        "_id": "5fc4c13f32ab3174acb08540",
        "userId": "go05111",
        "gender": "male"
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5fc4c2d6b3a2a054d4dc1235",
    "userId": "car",
    "userTbId": {
        "_id": "5fc4c2d6b3a2a054d4dc462c",
        "userId": "Chips",
        "gender": "female"
    }   
}
```

I want to get the only { "gender" : "male" } object in proudct, like...

```
{
    "_id": "5fc4c13f32ab3174acb01234",
    "product": "watch",
    "userTbId": {
        "_id": "5fc4c13f32ab3174acb08540",
        "userId": "go05111",
        "gender": "male"
    }
}
```

so I query like this

```
router.get('/:gender', (req, res, next) => {
    Product.find({
        "userTbId.gender": req.params.gender
    })
    .populate({
        path: 'userTbId',
        match: {
            userId: req.params.userId
        }
    })
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        res.status(200).json({
            docs
        }); 
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

but the result is nothing returned.

I tried a few different ways, but it didn't work that I want.

how can I fix it in mongoose?

would you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only specific fields from a populate document like gender in your case, then try this,

```
Product.find({
    "userTbId.gender": req.params.gender
})
.populate({
    path: 'userTbId',
    match: { userId: req.params.userId },
    select: 'gender -_id -userId'
})
.exec()
```

Comment: I try this but nothing is returned, too. 
I think 'Converts the ObjectId of the userTbId of an existing product schema to populate and takes the value, so it cannot find the value from the find()'.